# Format 00001 number

Tags: java, spring

For example, I get the input number LP00001, LP00023, LP00010 in text format. How can I get a number (1, 23, 10) based on the data received, add one, and form, for example, LP00002, LP00024, LP00011?

```
System.out.printf("%s%05d%n", "LP", i);
```

it suits me, I don't understand how I can extract the number itself

I need a number that is for example in LP00032, that is, in fact I should get 32

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `String.format`.

Comment: Also look at String.substring and Integer.parseInt

Comment: Extract the number from the input.  For example, LP00999, the number extracted would be 999.  Add 1 to 999 which gives you 1000.  Then create a string that starts with "LP" followed by "0"s and the number 1000.  You will need to compute how many "0" to append to LP before you append the number 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **LP** is a pattern (always 2 characters at the begining of the string), you could do this:

```
String text = "LP00001";
int numericValue = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2)) + 1;
System.out.printf("%s%05d%n", "LP", numericValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use formatted io. A format string with `%s` to indicate a `String` for the "LP" component. And then `%05d` to indicate five decimals zero filled. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s%05d%n", "LP", i);
}
```

Outputs

```
LP00000
LP00001
LP00002
LP00003
LP00004
LP00005
LP00006
LP00007
LP00008
LP00009
```

Comment: a cycle is certainly good, but how will it help me to pull out a number and add one?

Comment: Also the number can go up to 09231 for example

Comment: Your System.out.printf suits me, I don't understand how I can extract the number itself

Comment: @ДжейкМорган See `i` above.

Comment: I don't need i, I need a number that is for example in LP00032, that is, in fact I should get 32